# How can I center the content of my columns on mobile devices?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

Here's my code:

```
 <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3  example nopadding"><img src="holder.js/292x180" class="img-responsive"></div>
```

On small, medium, and large devices, I'm fine with the image positioning. But on mobile devices, I would like my image to be centered inside the row.

I've attempted to use "center-block" but that simply centers everything. I tried using offsets specifically for "xs" but it didn't produce a consistent look across all devices with 768 pixels of screen width and lower. What else would you guys suggest I do?

Edit: I realize this piece of CSS might be important. It's the only CSS I've added on top of the base Bootstrap CSS.

`.nopadding {
        padding: 0 !important;
        margin: 0 !important;
    }`

Comment: Can you make a demo on http://bootply.com/new

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could try to use a media query to target the col-xs-12 and center the image only then:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 400px){
 .col-xs-12.example {
  text-align: center;
 }
}
```

remove the `nopadding` class.

Comment: Is there a way to do it while keeping the nopadding class? I'd like for the other contents in my larger grants to completely fill the parent element.

Comment: Just had to create a few other media queries to get the right effect. Thanks!

Comment: you could leave the nopadding class, i thought this was a class just for aligning the images that you tried.

Answer (score 1):

because you did not provide a demo I had to guess what you actually want.

Here is a Demo how I think what u want and what to do. [Fiddle Demo](http://fiddle.jshell.net/dN2j3/)

To explain, I changed the Image from inline to be a block element, than you can use margin and auto to keep it in the center.

```
.img-responsive {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```